# None in Python Code

Tags: python

I am new to python and to test it I created a simple palindrome program. I am facing an issue that whenever I pass arguments to my function, I am returned a 'None' with the required answer. Can anyone tell em the reason behind this.  Please have a look at my code

```
try:

    def reverse_string1(s):
        return s[::-1]

    def calculate_palindrome(c):
        c = c.lower()
        b = reverse_string1(c)
        if c == b:
            print("String {0} is palindrome".format(c))
        else:
            print("String {0} is not palindrome".format(c))


    print(calculate_palindrome('Anna'))
    print(calculate_palindrome('caca'))
    print(calculate_palindrome('alula'))
    print(calculate_palindrome('test'))

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

I get the following return

```
String anna is palindrome
None
String mama is not palindrome
None
String alula is palindrome
None
String test is not palindrome
None
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `calculate_palindrome` does not return anything explicitly, but you try to use the value it returns when you say `print(calculate_palindrome('Anna'))` etc. In this and other such cases, where a value is expected but none is provided, python uses `None` as the value.

If you want to use it as a procedure (i.e. not use the "missing" return value), then just call it: `calculate_palindrome('Anna')`.

Alternatively,  you can write it as, say, a boolean function that returns `True` or `False`, instead of printing the message. Then you can use that value to test and print the appropriate message:

```
def calculate_palindrome(c):
    c = c.lower()
    b = reverse_string1(c)
    if c == b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

or perhaps a bit more idiomatically:

```
def calculate_palindrome(c):
    c = c.lower()
    b = reverse_string1(c)
    return b == c
```

Then you can use the returned value like this:

```
if calculate_palindrome('Anna'):
   print("Anna is a palindrome")
```

Comment: Thanks guys! The comments helped clear the confusion :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a value from a function using "return".  Otherwise the default is to return None.  You're not returning anything from calculate_palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

In python, a function that doesn't explicitly return anything returns `None`. Since your function prints internally, and you're printing the result of the function, you get two print statements: the first from inside the function, and the second, the result of the return value (`None`, implicitly)